# Issues Embedding JPG Images into a WPF Application

Tags: .net, wpf, deployment, resources, clickonce

No matter what I do, I cannot get my jpeg image to appear when running the application.  I need to be able to deploy this application with all the images present.

I have an image in my resources called BinOpticsLogo.  It is linked to an image here

> C:\Users\kyle.formeck\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\AOILibrary\VisualInspectionConsole\VisualInspectionConsole_currentFasterDBUploads\WaferTracker\binopticslogo_full.jpg.

The properties of this image are:

```
Build Action = Resource
Copy To Output Directory = Copy Always
```

XAML Code referencing this image:

```
    <Image 
        Source="binopticslogo_full.jpg"
        Height="23"/>
```

In my resources, the BinOpticsLogo resources Persistence property is set to Embedded in .resx

I see the image properly in the designer, but when I run the application, I never see the image.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

-Kyle

Comment: Try with a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: I try using this:  pack://application,,,/Resources/BinOpticsLogo.jpg  as my pack URI, but it still does not work

Comment: but your image is not physically inside a folder named resources... Why did you add that? remove the `/Resources/`.

Comment: it is inside a folder named Resources.  If you look at my project folder, there is a folder called Resources.  As a matter of fact, if i delete the \Resources from the pack uri, my designer turns white and displays a NotSupportedException: No information was found about this pixel format

Comment: I have not idea about designer issues. I don't use the VS WPF designer. I actually changed the .XAML file extension in the Solution Explorer to by default open with code editor and not designer.

Comment: I dont use the designer either, I write my entire UI in xaml.  I use the designer to let me see what things look like before I run the app.  For some reason, I can see the logo in the designer window; but when I run the app, the logo never shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!

Here is the updated XAML code that made it all work:

```
    <Image
        Height="23">
        <Image.Source>
            <ImageSource>/WaferTracker;component/Resources/BinOpticsLogo.jpg</ImageSource>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```